# buddypress functions not working in wordpress functions file

Tags: wordpress, function, buddypress

Hi I was tring to register a custom notification using bp_core_add_notification(). It works fine when I use it in any wp template files but when I try to use it in functions.php it won't work. I even tried to call the function wrapped with another function like:

```
function buddypress_activity_notification_add( $item_id='', $user_id='', $component_name='activity', $component_action='activity_liked', $secondary_item_id = '', $date_notified = false, $is_new = 1 ){

//echo 'called';
bp_core_add_notification( $item_id=$activity_id, $user_id, $component_name='activity', $component_action='activity_liked', $secondary_item_id = $user_id, $date_notified = false,$is_new = 1 ); 

}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in [bp-custom.php](http://codex.buddypress.org/plugindev/bp-custom-php/)